# react-sortable-hoc with table

Tags: reactjs, bulma, react-sortable-hoc

I'm trying to use [`react-sortable-hoc`](https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc/) with [bulma tables](https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/table/), so the `SortableItem` would be a `tr`. The problem is this: For a table row to obtain styling in bulma it needs to have some parent `table`-element with the class `table`. When trying to move the `tr`, because it's placed just before the end of the `body`-element, it doesn't have the `table`-parent anymore, all styling is lost and the row collapses.

How would I solve this? I have seen other drag-and-drop libraries (not react-specific) solving this kind of problem with essentially screenshotting the element and moving an `img` instead... it would already help me if I could manipulate how exactly the `tr` is appended to the body. Is there another lightweight dnd-react-library that could do this if I can't work it out with `react-sortable-hoc`? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this in the end using combination of the provided events (`updateBeforeSortStart` and `onSortStart`).
The approach goes like this:

1. Fetch the node in `updateBeforeStart`, save the styles for all of its children using `window.getComputedStyle`
2. In onSortStart, fetch the row (this is hardcoded as `document.querySelector(body > tr:last-of-type)`, which is a bit ugly and apply the style to all of its children

This was outlined [here](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/1c1f42ef43072f36776167c99532abdd3d31cef3/docs/patterns/tables.md) and was slightly modified by me.